# Security alert about libpng in my google play console

Tags: android, libpng, android-security

I received a security alert in my google play console about 2 applications ( games made by buildbox ) , the alert said that my application uses a version of libpng which presents a security flaw , I can't find this lib in my project , any solution please ?
they gives me this link also https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127

Answer (score 6):

If you are on a mac/linux machine, you can run the following command in your app directory to find which or your library is using libpng:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec fgrep libpng {} \; -print
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a search for "libpng" in your project folder?

Comment: I got a bunch of libngnative.so matches. Does anyone know what this is? It looks like a Android SDK thing.

Comment: when I search for libpng , I find nothing

Answer (score 0):

There is no "libpng" in buildbox project folders at all so you will not
find it when you search. If you feel you have received this vulnerability warning in error, contact our policy support team through the Google Play Developer Help Center. Try this because if there is no libpng how can there be
a security risk